# Oracle SQL sum up columns resulted from aggregate function and decode

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 4 columns resulted from different conditions `decode` and aggregate function `MAX`

```
SELECT MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Basic Salary',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Salary,
MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Transportation Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Transportation,
MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Mobile Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Mobile,
MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Housing Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Housing,
```

i want to make another column that sums up these values as `net salary` like this:

```
Salary + Mobile + Housing + Transportation AS "Net Salary"
```

but it doesn't seem to accept aliases, how can I achieve that? thanks in advance

Comment: use a CTE with your select and then use that to make the complete sum additional to the single columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can summarize all of them as formulas:

```
SELECT MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Basic Salary',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Salary,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Transportation Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Transportation,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Mobile Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Mobile,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Housing Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Housing,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Basic Salary',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) 
       +
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Transportation Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0))
       +
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Mobile Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0))
       +
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Housing Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) 
       AS "Net Salary"
FROM Table1
```

OR use a CTE to utilize aliases:

```
WITH max_table AS
(
SELECT MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Basic Salary',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Salary,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Transportation Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Transportation,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Mobile Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Mobile,
       MAX(DECODE(pett.element_name,'Housing Allowance',peevf.screen_entry_value,0)) Housing
FROM Table1
)

SELECT Salary,
       Transportation,
       Mobile,
       Housing,
       Salary + Transportation + Mobile + Housing AS "Net Salary"
FROM max_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a single row for each element name and you are trying to pivot rows to columns then you can use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(
         CASE
         WHEN pett.element_name = 'Basic Salary'
         THEN peevf.screen_entry_value
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS Salary,
       MAX(
         CASE 
         WHEN pett.element_name = 'Transportation Allowance'
         THEN peevf.screen_entry_value
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS Transportation,
       MAX(
         CASE
         WHEN pett.element_name = 'Mobile Allowance'
         THEN peevf.screen_entry_value
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS Mobile,
       MAX(
         CASE
         WHEN pett.element_name = 'Housing Allowance'
         THEN peevf.screen_entry_value
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS Housing,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN pett.element_name IN (
                'Basic Salary', 'Transportation Allowance',
                'Mobile Allowance', 'Housing Allowance'
              )
         THEN peevf.screen_entry_value
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS net_salary,
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(salary, 0) AS salary,
       COALESCE(transport, 0) AS transport,
       COALESCE(mobile, 0) AS mobile,
       COALESCE(housing, 0) AS housing,
       COALESCE(salary, 0) + COALESCE(transport, 0)
        + COALESCE(mobile, 0) + COALESCE(housing, 0) AS net_salary
FROM   ...
PIVOT (
  MAX(peevf.screen_entry_value)
  FOR pett.element_name IN (
    'Basic Salary' AS salary,
    'Transportation Allowance' AS transportation,
    'Mobile Allowance' AS mobile,
    'Housing Allowance' AS housing
  )
)
```